# List comprehension of powers of 2 in Python fails with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I tried to make a list comprehension of 2 to the power of x  (`2**x`) for a list of numbers, and I noticed that:

```
[2**x for x in [2, 100]] # works fine
```

However,

```
[2**x for x in np.array([2, 100])] # doesn't work.
[x for x in 2**np.array([2, 100])] # doesn't work.
```

But rather than error, the output is: `Out[98]: [4, 0]`. And yet:

```
[2**x for x in np.array([2, 10])] # works fine
[x for x in 2**np.array([2, 10])] # works fine
```

which is exactly the same, only a smaller number.

What could be the reason for this? I am using Python 3.6 in Spyder with the Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2^100 is too big for an int, you should set the type to object

```
[2**x for x in np.array([2, 100], dtype='object')]
```

will give

```
[4, 1267650600228229401496703205376]
```

Answer (score 4):

`np.array` converts the contents of the list to numpy types:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([2, 100])
>>> type(x[1])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

This is numpy's fixed length 64 bit integer.

Whereas in python, we get:

```
>>> y = [2, 100]
>>> type(y[1])
<class 'int'>
```

which is python's arbitrary sized integer (BigInteger in other languages)

For whatever reason (this is probably specced in numpy, but perhaps not the behaviour I'd expect!), numpy's `int64` overflows to zero:

```
>>> 2 ** np.int64(100)
0
```

(or more directly)

```
>>> 2 ** x[1]
0
```

The list comprehension in this case is a red herring, the actual *cause* of the difference is the conversion that `np.array` is doing.